# list index out of range error while performing web-scraping algorithm

Tags: python, web-scraping, jupyter-notebook

I have written a python program for web scraping in the jupyter notebook:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests 
page = requests.get(url)
#Store the contents of the website under doc
doc = lh.fromstring(page.content)
#Parse data that are stored between <tr>..</tr> of HTML
tr_elements = doc.xpath('//tr')
r = requests.get(url)
#Create empty list
col=[]
i=0
#For each row, store each first element (header) and an empty list
for t in tr_elements[0]:
    i+=1
    name=t.text_content()
    print ('%d:"%s"'%(i,name))
    col.append((name,[]))
```

This gives me error:

> IndexError
> ---> 16 for t in tr_elements[0]
> IndexError: list index out of range

How to solve this error?

I am also attaching the link for the jupyter notebook:
https://github.com/chirayupd/Mumbai_Neighbourhood_Analytics/blob/main/Neighbourhood.ipynb

Comment: Error indicating you don't have element in that index. i.e list is empty.
What you have in ```tr_elements```.

Also edit the full snippet might help.

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: https://github.com/chirayupd/Mumbai_Neighbourhood_Analytics/blob/main/Neighbourhood.ipynb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things.

Firstly, you could just grab the whole table with pandas and `.columns` to retrieve the headers.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html('https://mumbai7.com/postal-codes-in-mumbai/')[0]
print(list(df.columns)) # print list(df.columns)
print(df) # print df
```

---

Secondly, with `requests` you need an appropriate user-agent header e.g.

```
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)'})
```

---

Thirdly, `tr_elements[0]` will look at first row, you can then add on an additional call to retrieve the `th` elements from that row; so a re-write might look like the following:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://mumbai7.com/postal-codes-in-mumbai/', headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)'})
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
tr_elements = soup.select('tr')

col = []
i = 0

for th in tr_elements[0].select('th'): #  header row
    i+=1
    name = th.get_text()
    print('%d:"%s"'%(i,name)) # print ('%d:"%s"'%(i,name))
    col.append((name,[]))
```

Now, you can abbreviate that somewhat as follows, by using a type selector to pull only the `th` elements within the single table on the page, combined with enumerate (from 1) to remove the need for your counter variable:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://mumbai7.com/postal-codes-in-mumbai/', headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)'})
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')

for i, th in enumerate(soup.select('th'), 1):
    print(i, th.text)
    print()
```